# How to add my own custom User Control inside an UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, webforms, updatepanel

This is my User Control:

```
AutomezziEAttrezzature.ascx
```

and this is the function called by an `asp:DropDownList` at `OnSelectedIndexChanged` stage:

```
protected void ddCategoriaHasChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // my asp:Panel
    categoriaCaricata.Controls.Clear();
}
```

I want to add this control inside that `categoriaCaricata` panel. How can I do it? Someone warning me about using `DynamicControlsPlaceHolder`, but it is not clear how it works and why.

Can you give to me a smart example?

Answer (score 0):

You can register the control in your page:

`<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/AutomezziEAttrezzature.ascx" TagName="Automezzi" TagPrefix="uc1" %>`

and then use it

```
<uc1:Automezzi ID="ctlAutomezzi" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to assign properties to your UC, and load it dynamically, you should do somwthing like this"

### This is VB.net code (An example only), but should help you out as its pretty basic UC stuff

```
Dim myDatesControl As New UserControl
myDatesControl = Page.LoadControl("~/bookingControls/ucDates.ascx")

        With CType(myDatesControl, controls_ucDates)
            .checkInDate = Session("nowcheckin")
            .checkOutDate = Session("nowcheckout")
            .Nights = "xxx"
            .guid = currentBookingFilter.guid
            .ExtraInfo = currentBookingFilter
        End With

mypanel.controls.add(myDatesControl)
```

If you don't need to assign dynamic properties, then just add your control to the panel/page manually, design time, and hide it. The you can show it when you need to.